# How to disable implicit building in packages? {$IMPLICITBUILD}

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm working on a couple of custom packages (containing GUI components mostly) for a Delphi XE2 application. I need the [$IMPLICITBUILD](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsimplicitbuild_xml.html) directive to be off. I've edited the package .BPL file manually to set `{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}` but the Delphi IDE occasionally reverts the directive to `{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}`. I'm guessing manually editing the .BPL file is not the correct approach. How should I set $IMPLICITBUILD so that it stays off?

I've googled but can't find anything, nor can I see anything when poking around the Delphi IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Project Options for the package, on the Description page, in Build Control section, select "Explicit rebuild".